# .NET Core how to validate JS code at runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, .net-core

I have a C# .NET Framework app which has some React Views and some blocks where users can input JS code. The validation of said JS code is done having node.exe alongside my app executable.

Now, I'm migrating the code to .NET Core, to work in both Windows and Mac/Linux. Thus, I can't have node.exe in my app executable, and I don't want to have 3 different binaries, one for each OS, alongside the app.

So, **I'm trying to find a cross-platform alternative to node**, in order to validate JS code at runtime via C#.

I've been searching online for a while and haven't figure out the solution.

Any way of having a node library only to execute via .NET Core? Any other alternative?

Comment: Have you tried https://validatejs.org ?

Comment: @NishanChathuranga thanks for the answer. Looking into that project's github, it says that I still need node.js...